# Using Mono SGen Garbage collector in C/C++ programs

Tags: c++, c, mono, garbage-collection

Is it possible to use [SGen garbage collector](http://www.mono-project.com/Compacting_GC) (from the mono runtime) in coventionnal C/C++ programs ?
I think mono used also the [Boehm-Demers-Weiser](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/) conservative garbage collector that can be used in C/C++ programs.

Comment: Why would you want to commit such an unnatural act?

Comment: I don't think that this is possible. From the looks of it, SGen seems to be a GC which is specifically designed to work with the Mono-Structure/Runtime.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are very few dependencies on the rest of the Mono code in SGen, so it should be easy to extract it out and adapt to other uses.
The major difference from the Boehm collector is that it currently doesn't support a non-precise mode for heap objects, so you can't use it to replace malloc easily.
It would work great, though, for managing objects for which you could provide precise reference information.

Comment: From the looks of it should be, at least, a very interesting experiment. Please share your experience.

Answer (score -2):

Not sure about the garbage collector that you have specified. But do you really need to use a GC on a C++ project? I never felt the use of a GC in my C++ projects. You should be good if you follow the best practices and use a decent smart pointer.

Comment: No, I don't realy need a GC. But am curious !

Comment: While it is true that GC is not needed for most C++ projects, there are ones that do need it.  There are also times you would want to interface Mono and C++ code that would require access to Mono's GC stack.